# Skipping incompatible error when compiling mysql library using arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: compiling, mysql, c++, arm

All problems posted related to mysql library use standard gcc compiler. However, I need to compile a project running on a beaglebone black device. Hence, I am using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` instead of `gcc`.

Here is my environment:

- Ubuntu - 32 bit
- using eclipse luna c++
- mysql running fine on beaglebone. Now, I am writing code to access mysql using C++.

Please help to fix my error. thanks 
compiling using a standard gcc works fine, so it means i already installed

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
apt-get install mysql-client
apt-get install mysql-server
```

---

So, this is what i get after compiling:

```
12:38:15 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project arm2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/arm2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/mysql -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/mysql/cppconn -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.8.2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/arm2.d" -MT"src/arm2.d" -o "src/arm2.o" "../src/arm2.cpp"
../src/arm2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/arm2.cpp:32:10: warning: variable ‘driver’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  Driver *driver;
          ^
Finished building: ../src/arm2.cpp

Building target: arm2
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsf -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib -o "arm2"  ./src/arm2.o   -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.a when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/../lib/libmysqlcppconn.so when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libmysqlcppconn.so when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libmysqlcppconn.a when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.a when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so when searching for -lmysqlcppconn
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [arm2] Error 1

12:38:18 Build Finished (took 2s.451ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first remove these options because your linker is trying to find in these paths (which clearly have not the .so files): -L/usr/lib/mysql -L/usr/lib
and find and copy these files from your BBB to your machine:

```
libmysqlclient.a
libmysqlclient.so
ld-linux.so.3
ld-linux-armhf.so.3
libmysqlclient.a
libmysqlclient.so
libz.so.1
```

then add -L these files to your linker option.

Finally, add these options to your linker:

```
-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -ldl
```